# Issues/warnings with React-native init (no-lockfile;connect2.x series is deprecated;react has unmet peer dependency)

Tags: react-native

I am using react native init to initialize my project, and I'm getting some warnings, which I'm sure will come to bite me in the back later on If I don't deal with them now. **In bold are the concerning messages**. I'm not entirely sure what to do about them, can anyone inform me how to fix this/if I'm doing something wrong that I am receiving these messages/warnings? A beginner friendly/light on the terminology answer would be appreciated, as I'm new to react native

yarn add v0.27.5  
**info No lockfile found.**      
[1/4] Resolving packages...      
**warning react-native > connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated** 
[2/4] Fetching packages... 
[3/4] Linking dependencies... 
**warning "react-native@0.47.2" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.12".**

This react-native init  command is also taking very long (~ 5 minutes per use). Are the above warnings causing the long startup time, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**info** is just some infomation, not a problem

and for the two **warning**:

- ### deprecated connect

  about the deprecated connect version,I came up with too, it's because react-native depends on connect, and react-native's latest version is 0.49.3, it use connect@2.30.2,a little bit deprecated, and there's someone made a pr about this problem,  [Github:pr](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16380)
  ,but has not been merged because of some test coverage, so now just ignore this warning;
- ### unmet peer dependency

  it's related to some deprecated package.

Comment: about deprecated connect , news is [upgrade pr](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16380#issuecomment-344677730) this pr will upgrade connect

Answer (score 3):

All I've found to solve these warnings is to:

1) Update all react-native packages

```
npm install react-native@latest --save
```

- This can often solve problems with outdated/deprecated npm packages

2) Install react@16.0.0-alpha.12

```
npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.12
```

3) Update connect@2.30.2

```
npm update connect@2.30.2
```

Again, warnings #1 and #2 are pretty common

Comment: This is the right answer I guess. First, checking the current version by using the command of `npm view connect versions` then `connect` can be updated to the latest version in my case proper command was `npm update connect@3.6.6`.

Answer (score 1):

The "No lockfile found" just means that the installation hadn't been run before; the lockfile keeps track of exact installed package versions.

Searching for the other two are how I got here so I'm not going to be any help on those (yet). ;-).