# react-native - warnings setting up basic project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I was trying to init a project in ReactNative using CLI and the command I gave was:
`npx react-native init testy`
The output looks like this:

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\Users\Vipul\ReactProjects\testy
Using yarn v1.19.1
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.19.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native > fbjs-scripts > core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > fbjs > core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > metro-babel-register > core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro-core > jest-haste-map > fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-native > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.56.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".
warning " > react-native@0.61.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.9.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 381 new dependencies.
...
...
info Setting up new React Native app in C:\Users\Vipul\ReactProjects\testy
info Adding required dependencies
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 179 new dependencies.
...
...
info Adding required dev dependencies
yarn add v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["@babel/core@^7.7.2"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\Vipul\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@babel-core-7.7.2-ea5b99693bcfc058116f42fa1dd54da412b29d91-integrity\\node_modules\\@babel\\core" as pattern ["@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.0.0","@babel/core@^7.1.0","@babel/core@^7.1.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.7.2"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\Vipul\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@babel-runtime-7.7.2-111a78002a5c25fc8e3361bedc9529c696b85a6a-integrity\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime" as pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.0.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
```

The package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "testy",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Now I want to know if these warnings are going to affect my project later. How can I remove them and even though I did not specify them why is RN even using incorrect or unmet dependency?

Please note that I tried to build a RN project before this too and here [React Native - Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from 'index.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989571/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequirede) is the error I got stuck at and started with a fresh project then.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, no it shouldn't affect your project. React native depends on a number of core dependencies and with every update, it tries to reduce these core dependencies. However, this SO response should explain better.

I hope this helps.

[Issues/warnings with React-native init (no-lockfile;connect2.x series is deprecated;react has unmet peer dependency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824422/issues-warnings-with-react-native-init-no-lockfileconnect2-x-series-is-depreca/46970799)

Answer (score 0):

this fix works for following error.

with npm:

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime
```

or with yarn:

```
yarn add @babel/runtime
```

and build project again with

```
npm run start --reset-cache
```

Comment: No it does not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989571/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequirede

Answer (score 0):

Just in case other people search this error again. 
For my case, I solve it by updating my yarn packages.

```
npm install -g yarn
```